Degrees of freedom for biased sample autocorrelation function
I want to find the expression for the a biased estimate of the autocorrelation function for a time series $X$, and am doing this from the biased estimated autocovariance function for lag $k$, divided by the biased autocovariance at lag 0:
\begin{equation}
\hat{\rho}_{xx}\big[k\big] = \frac{\hat{\gamma}_{xx}\big[k\big]}{\hat{\gamma}_{xx}\big[0\big]} = \frac{\displaystyle \mathrm{E}\big[\left(X_t-\mu_x\right)\left(X_{t+k}-\mu_x\right)\big]}{\displaystyle\mathrm{E}\big[\left(X-\mu_x\right)^2\big]}
\end{equation}
I thought that:
\begin{equation}
\hat{\sigma}_{xx}^2 = \hat{\gamma}_{xx}\big[0\big]=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(X_i-\mu_x\right)^2
\end{equation}
such that:
\begin{equation}
\hat{\gamma}_{xx}\big[k\big]=\left(\frac{1}{n-k-1}\right)\sum_{i=1}^{n-k} \left(X_i-\mu_x\right)\left(X_{i+k}-\mu_x\right)
\end{equation}
so:
\begin{equation}
\hat{\rho}_{xx}\big[k\big] = \left(\frac{n-1}{n-k-1}\right)\left(\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n-k} \left(X_i-\mu_x\right)\left(X_{i+k}-\mu_x\right)}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \left(X_i-\mu_x\right)^2}\right)
\end{equation}
Which accounts for both the bias in estimating the mean in both numerator and denominator, and the bias introduced by the diminishing number of pairs of $\left(X_i,\, X_{i+k}\right)$.
However here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation it suggests:
\begin{equation}
\hat{R}\big[k\big]=\frac{1}{(n-k)\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n-k} \left(X_i-\mu_x\right)\left(X_{i+k}-\mu_x\right)
\end{equation}
which is correct? And what is incorrect in my reasoning?

do you have brian ripley's text "Modern Applied Statistics with S" ( I'm pretty sure it's called that ). If so, there's a formula in there for an unbiased estimate of the ACF and it's neither of the above. I think it's because both of the estimators you refer to are biased. If you don't have the text, I might be able to find a free copy. So, let me know.

Here's a free copy of the book. The formula is on page 390 and there is some explanation behind it. http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~houbo/course/Modern%20Applied%20Statistics%20with%20Splus%20(Fourth%20edition).pdf

@mlofton - thank you!  That book is now filed.  I am only asking because there seems to be an inconsistency in the biased estimators (if one compares the overall estimate to the components therein).  I'll edit the post to make that clearer.

Okay. yes, I can't explain the difference between the two. A lot of times, these things may have the unbiased correction term in there incorrectly but they don't explain how it got there ?

What are you calling $\mu_x$ ? Is it the known expectation of $X$ or is it the empirical mean? In the Wikipedia article, it is the known mean.

@Pohoua  - it would be the empirical mean

Ok so the difference between the wikipedia's article and you comes from there.
